# Array of characters copy error

Tags: c++, arrays, character

My question is this, when the inner for loop exits, and enters back into the outer for loop it stops adding characters to the string pointer pstrDestination. Can some one explain that to me, I am not terminating the array of character so it should still write, shouldn't it?

```
// Does it match
if (strcmp(strCompareString, pstrToFind) == 0)
{

    // Reset the index of the found letter
    intFoundLetterIndex = (intFoundLetterIndex - intCompareIndex);

    // Add the characters from source to destination.
    for (intSourceIndex = 0; intSourceIndex < intSourceLength; intSourceIndex += 1)
    {

        pstrDestination[intDestinationIndex] = pstrSource[intSourceIndex];
        intDestinationIndex += 1;

        // Are we at the beginning of the target word
        if (intSourceIndex == intFoundLetterIndex)
        {

            // Add the replacement characters to the destination.
            for (intNewIndex = 0; intNewIndex < intReplaceWithLength; intNewIndex += 1)
            {

                pstrDestination[intDestinationIndex - 1] = pstrReplaceWith[intNewIndex];
                intDestinationIndex += 1;

            }

            intSourceIndex += intToFindLength;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. Did you step through your code using the debugger already?

Comment: You should learn about `++` and `--` for incrementing and decrementing variables.

Comment: `intDestinationIndex - 1;` What do you think this statement actually does?

Comment: yes, Okay I am replacing a word in an string, but instead of using the built in string Data Type I am using an Array of Characters. When I reach the point where the word I want to replace begins, I replace it with a new word or phrase. but when the replacement is done, and I exit out of the inner for loop. The outer for loop chugs along like it should but it stops adding characters to pstrDestination, its like it is terminated, but I dont terminate the string.

Comment: // Yes, set Destination index back 1
            intDestinationIndex - 1;
 Sorry I decided to do it in the loop parameters instead of before entering the loop, I meant to comment that out. Yes I know it should be -=.

Comment: The continue statement is redundant.

Comment: Barmar, I prefer readability over short hand.

Comment: I added the continue statement to see if it by some chance would brute force it to work. Alas it didnt.

Comment: So nobody wants to take a stab at answering the question? I agree with all the input about intDestinationIndex and the Continue statement being redundant, but I am looking for a concise technical answer. I know I need a new solution I am just looking for why this is behaving this way.

Comment: @user3119737 You didn't put enough effort into properly framing your question.  Here is a list of the shortcomings: 1. You didn't indicate what this piece of code is supposed to do. 2. You didn't show the declaration/initialization of your variables.  Who knows what `intCompareIndex` is supposed to be. 3. The Hungarian notation sucks (well, technically it's the camelCase that sucks).  It's very difficult to disambiguate visually between `intCompareIndex`, `intSourceIndex`, `intSourceLength`, etc. 4. Too many variables (though arguably, this is one of the things we are supposed to fix for you).

Comment: Kevin I commend you on you highly technical answer. I will take it into consideration. also the prefix tells you what it is and the name is descriptive enough a 3 year old can read it. Also too many variables? i would like an explanation as to 1. Why it is too many variables? 2. Where in my question do I ask you to fix the amount of variables?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can come up with is, The Visual Studio 2013 IDE is trying to give me a huge big ol' hug. 
It is terminating the string for me.
if I step the index back 1 and set the spot in the array equal to ' '. Then the loop executes as expected cause I over wrote the terminator.

after the inner loop I added;

```
pstrDestination[intDestinationIndex - 1] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this

```
intDestinationIndex - 1;
```

should look like this:

```
intDestinationIndex -= 1;
```